# How can I refresh the packages installed by a vendor dependency?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using a Symfony 5.4, and I'd like to update/refresh some vendor assets dependencies, but I can't find the way of doing it.

As an example, when diving into one of the dependencies in the vendor, in this case [ezplatform-admin-ui-assets](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezplatform-admin-ui-assets), I can see that the `package.json` defines the dependency `"moment-timezone": "^0.5.32"`. When looking into the installation of that dependency in the `vendor/{{bundle-name}}/Resources/public/` directory I find that the version being installed is the version `0.5.34`, when currently the NPM package has until version `0.5.43` ([source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone)).

Why is this happening? Is it possible to force or refresh the package installation of a vendor dependency? I would like the vendor to install the newest version possible, defined by the **own** bundle. Removing the `vendor` folder and executing `composer install` and `assets:install` doesn't seem to work.

By the way, there is no other bundle that is trying to install the `"moment-timezone"` package, so there shouldn't be any conflicts.

Comment: It is up to the package maintainer to update any dependencies once they have verified that any updates don't break any of _their_ code. There isn't really any way you can force this process. If the updated dependency has features that you would like to make use of, you could fork the repository, implement the changes, test it, and then submit a PR, but if the package maintainer chooses to ignore your PR then there's not much more you can do. You could of course start using your fork instead, but then hey, congrats, you are now the maintainer.

Comment: Following the example, aren't they already configuring the dependency with `"moment-timezone": "^0.5.32"`, which means that any package (from `^0.5.32` to `0.5.43 (currently)`) should be installable? I mean, a `package-lock.json` is not provided by the bundle, so the package shouldn't be fixed, right?

Comment: It could be because the package is not yet at version 1, which means Composer is a bit more strict at upgrading from the version specified. [See the documentation at getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-)

Comment: That's a really good point! Unfortunately, following the documentation, versions prior to 1 like this one should not install the current version being installed.

Right now `"moment-timezone": "^0.5.32"` is installing `0.5.34`. If I'm not wrong, the documentation specifies that `^0.5.32` should install `0.5.32 < 0.5.33`, which doesn't make much sense 0.o

Comment: My bad! I double checked the docs and I was wrong. `"^0.5.32"`specifies `0.5.32 < 0.6`. 
The difference with a 1 version would be: `"^1.5.32"` specifies `1.5.32 < 2.0.0`.

In conclusion: I don't know why it's installing `0.5.34` ^^'

Comment: If this is about frontend dependencies: please adjust the tagging, this problem is not related to Symfony or PHP